# Swap thumbnail image and change css for the clicked image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagesource

I am  trying to swap the images of thumbnails with the main image and then kind of put a border of color blue out of the clicked image. I tried to do document.getelemnt by id and then put the id of the thumbnail image but it changes on the first thumbnail image css not the one which is clicked.

Here is my code and script i am using. I tries the visited css but not working.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#gallery li img").click(function(){
        $('#main-img').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));

    });
    var imgSwap = [];
     $("#gallery li img").each(function(){
        imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
        imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
        document.getElementById("thumb-img").style.border = "2px blue solid";
        document.getElementById("thumb-img").style.opacity = "1";
    });
    $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;

    });
}
</script>

<div class="container">

    <div id="gallery" class="col-md-12">
    <img src="1.png" alt="" id="main-img"/>
    <li id="thumb"><img src="http://cdn.resize.sparkplatform.com/fl/1024x768/true/20161107174518882259000000-o.jpg" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" id="thumb-img" /></li>
     <li id="thumb"><img src="1.png" alt="" class="img-thumbnail"  id="thumb-img"/></li>
```

Comment: `"thumb-img:first"` is not a valid `id`. Use `querySelector()` instead of `.getElementById()` And, why is all of your code surrounded with `{` and `}`. Clean up your code and then errors will become easier to spot and fix.

Comment: {} added by stack overflow to add code in between. how to use query selector can you give an example

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't add those to your code. You are supposed to highlight your code and then click that button, which indents it properly. You are also using the same `id`s on multiple elements, which is not allowed. `id`s are meant to be unique. `getElementById()` only works properly when you pass a valid (and unique) `id` to it. You aren't doing that, you are passing a not unique `id` along with a JQuery filter `:first`. There is so much wrong with your code, you need to go back and correct all the syntax errors before you can move forward with your image problem.

Comment: You also aren't showing all of the relevant HTML. You are missing the closing `<div>` tags and your `<li>` elements are not nested within an `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: @ScottMarcus please check now.

Comment: You still have most of the problems I've already told you about. It looks like  all you've done is re-format the code, but not actually changed it.